# Simualting ThreadDeath Exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

how can i simulate the threaddeath exception in java programming, in what scenario this will occurr, can any one give example, to throw the threaddeath exception.

Thanks:

```
public class ThreadDeathCatch {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     try {
       Thread t = new Thread() {
         public void run() {
           try {
             Thread.sleep(2500);
           } catch (Throwable ex)  {
               ex.printStackTrace();
             System.out.println("Caught in run: " + ex);
           }
         }
       };
       t.start();
       // Give t time to get going...
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       t.stop();        // EXPECT COMPILER WARNING
     } catch (Throwable t) {
       System.out.println("Caught in main: " + t);
     }
   }
 }
```

**this is the example to throw Threaddeath, it uses Thread.stop is there any other  wrong scenario where thread death can occur in multithreaded environment without using Thread.stop**

> Any thoughts ?

Comment: At least half of your question can be answered by reading [the `ThreadDeath` documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadDeath.html).

Comment: What is your *specific* question ?

Comment: i need a live program that throws threaddeath exception

Comment: @anish: try `throw new ThreadDeath();`.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("Trying to kill current thread");
try {
    Thread.currentThread().stop();
} catch (final ThreadDeath ex) {
    System.out.println("Ugh I'm dead");
    throw ex;
}
```